# How to add additional payload to botframework messages (DirectLine)

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm developing bot using MS Bot Framework.
We have native mobile app client for this bot also, so the only option for us is to use DirectLine API via sockets.

I wonder if it possible to add custom payload to messages which bot send to the client.

Say I want to return a message which will have 20 locations, every location is a ThumbnailCard attachment with image, title, subtitle and text, I also want to add more information like `lat, lon, open time, close time etc.` What is the best way to do this, is this possible?

I'm using NodeJS for my bot. And my IDE telling me that currently only these options are available for every ThumbnailCard attachment:

- text
- title
- subtitle
- images
- tap

Previously I was using approach like this:

`message = new builder.Message(session)
        .attachments(thumbnails)
        .attachmentLayout('carousel')
        .entities([
            {
                name: 'Location 1',
                lat: 10.11,
                lon: 10.11
            },
            {
                name: 'Mitul',
                lat: 10.11,
                lon: 10.11
            }
        ])
        .text('Select Location');`

but then I found that if I supply 1 or 2 items in entities, than I receive it in my app, but if there are 5-10 objects with 10-30 properties, then I see not entities in the client at all. I think I'm using `entities` wrong here.

What is the best approach to add custom data to my bot messages, and are there any size limitation like how much objects I can pass along?

Comment: I believe `entities` is intended for entities returned by AI. You might be able to use the `channelData` instead?

Comment: @stuartd thanks I was able to send my data as channelData, but then I checked Log Stream in Azure and found this message `Message.setChannelData() is deprecated. Use Message.sourceEvent() instead.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `sourceEvent` property of the message. It's usually used to send payloads that are specific/native to a channel.

Before Direct Line v3.0, attachments were not supported, and so the Direct Line sample was using the `sourceEvent` property to send them. You can see that in this [code snapshot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/commit/0ef8a553b00b373e613182a9b6f8fecba6bff8bd#diff-b53eade3b8c3cbb0a229c08f41875ffaL35).

[image]

Comment: This approach works, thank you! I was able to send about 49 objects as a payload, if I send more objects I receive 500 server error. I converted my object into JSON string and it's length was: 149 597, so the limit is somewhere about 150K symbols when converted to JSON